# gmapping and rplidar

Tags: ros, navigation, rplidar, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi friends....
I will not play a sample bag file.
I couldnt solve gmapping with rplidar

how can ı build a map as best simple.

Can you give me a launch file for simple create a map with rplidar.
I have rplidar node and gmapping nodes and laser_Scan _matchers tools.

I mean a lunch file like this.

##### publish an example base_link -> laser transform

##### start the laser scan_matcher

```
<param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
<param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
```

##### start rviz

##### start gmapping

```
<param name="map_udpate_interval" value="1.0"/>
<param name="maxUrange" value="5.0"/>
<param name="sigma" value="0.1"/>
<param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
<param name="lstep" value="0.15"/>
<param name="astep" value="0.15"/>
<param name="iterations" value="1"/>
<param name="lsigma" value="0.1"/>
<param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
<param name="lskip" value="1"/>
<param name="srr" value="0.1"/>
<param name="srt" value="0.2"/>
<param name="str" value="0.1"/>
<param name="stt" value="0.2"/>
<param name="linearUpdate" value="1.0"/>
<param name="angularUpdate" value="0.5"/>
<param name="temporalUpdate" value="0.4"/>
<param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
<param name="particles" value="10"/>
<param name="xmin" value="-5.0"/>
<param name="ymin" value="-5.0"/>
<param name="xmax" value="5.0"/>
<param name="ymax" value="5.0"/>
<param name="delta" value="0.02"/>
<param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
<param name="llsamplestep" value="0.05"/>
<param name="lasamplerange" value="0.05"/>
<param name="lasamplestep" value="0.05"/>
```

please help me....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211180/gmapping-and-rplidar/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if you still need this, but your problem most likely has to do with differences between how RPLIDAR and general ROS frames. Take a look [here](http://geduino.blogspot.ca/2015/04/gmapping-and-rplidar.html) and that should fix your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0